# Error:Invalid data, chunk must be a string or buffer, not object when running ionic -v

Tags: ionic-framework, cmd

[Error in cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coonQ.png)

I've tried uninstalling ionic, cordova and node.js and reinstalling them two times. One with lts node and the othe, current lts.But the error still persists. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For somoe reason, npm uninstallof cordova, ionic, and the like didnt remove the files which explains those red characters I saw but did not mind. So to those who also encountered this problem, go to C:\Users\YourAccName\AppData\Roaming and manually delete npm and npm-cache files. After that, you may reinstall ionic then cordova. It worked for me :)
[Finally!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnZC1.png)